# How to disable login and password autocomplete by browser on creating and editing user pages?

Tags: html, browser, autocomplete, passwords, autofill

Browsers remember login and password and offer to fill inputs automatically when creating and editing user. I want it to be enabled only on login page. Setting `autocomplete` to `off` for whole form and every input doesn't help. I changed password input's type to `text` and modified it to `password` using JavaScript after page loads, but it also doesn't help. It seems that it doesn't matter what are values of `name` and `id` attributes - it always offers filling login and password for every `<input type="password" />` element with one `<input type="text" />` element preceding it.

This is fragment of my code in Razor view for creating new user (below is also plain HTML):

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-3" })
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-3" })
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-3" })
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

The same code with ASP.NET MVC helpers converted to HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="Email">Email address</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-email="The Email address field is not a valid e-mail address." data-val-required="The Email address field is required." id="Email" name="Email" type="text" value="" />
        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Email" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="Password">Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-length="The Password must be at least 6 characters long." data-val-length-max="100" data-val-length-min="6" data-val-required="The Password field is required." id="Password" name="Password" type="password" />
        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Password" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="ConfirmPassword">Confirm password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-equalto="The password and confirmation password do not match." data-val-equalto-other="*.Password" data-val-required="The Confirm password field is required." id="ConfirmPassword" name="ConfirmPassword" type="password" />
        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="ConfirmPassword" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I inserted  fake `input` element without `id` and `name` between `input` elements for login and password:

```
<input type="text" class="fakeInputToDisableCredentialsAutocomplete" />
```

I cannot hide it with setting `display` attribute to `none`. It must have its `visibility` value set to `hidden` and `position` value set to `absolute` to prevent displacing some other elements.

```
.fakeInputToDisableCredentialsAutocomplete{
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden; 
}
```

It also solves problem for input with password confirmation, but I put it before every `input` with `type="password"` just in case. I tested it in Google Chrome, Internet Explorer 11 and Microsoft Edge.

Comment: Before I accept my answer I will wait for more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions for it:

1. Insert a fake hidden input box between Username and password
2. Split User Name and password into 2 pages

for fake hidden input box, It works for IE, Chrome, Firefox. But don't work for Safari